# What is the H matrix in a kalman filter

Tags: kalman-filter

I am trying to write a kalman filter and I'm stuck on the H matrix. Right now I'm trying to get position and velocity data and I'm providing position, velocity and acceleration data. How do you set up an H matrix for this, or just in general?

Comment: Welcome to SO! [This may help](http://www.bzarg.com/p/how-a-kalman-filter-works-in-pictures/)

Comment: Thank You! I think that means that the H matrix is just used to convert from the raw sensor units to the desired output units?

Comment: Welcome to SO please consider posting code so we can halp on specific problem.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 good articles about Kalman filter I used to understand how it works and how matrices should be set up:

- http://www.bzarg.com/p/how-a-kalman-filter-works-in-pictures/
- https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Kalman_filter#/Example_application

H matrix is **the observation matrix**.

> [image]

It means, that if we have a simple model with variable position (x) and velocity (x') and our sensor provides us **observations** for positions (z), that we will have:
[image]
[image]